# MacOS Homebrew Easy-Rsa wont sign CSR: '$ easyrsa sign-req server home-server' easyrsa_openssl - Command has failed: openssl ca -utf8 -batch -in

Tags: macos, homebrew, monterey, certificate, open-source

I am trying to build an OpenVPN certificate for an openvpn server on MacOS using Easy-Rsa from Homebrew installation. I am following these instructions from the downloadable guide here: https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=318795

I generated my CA with a password, which later down the line in the easy-rsa process, causes things to fail. If I don't use a CA password, then easy-rsa doesn't use openssl, and thus doesn't fail in the process.

I am at the step of trying to sign my CSR file.

```
dan@dans-MacBook-Pro certs % easyrsa sign-req server home-server
Using Easy-RSA 'vars' configuration:
* /tmp/certs/pki/vars

Using SSL:
* openssl OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023)
You are about to sign the following certificate:
Please check over the details shown below for accuracy. Note that this request
has not been cryptographically verified. Please be sure it came from a trusted
source or that you have verified the request checksum with the sender.
Request subject, to be signed as a server certificate
for '1095' days:

subject=
    commonName                = home-server

Type the word 'yes' to continue, or any other input to abort.
  Confirm request details: yes

Using configuration from /tmp/certs/pki/openssl-easyrsa.cnf
Enter pass phrase for /tmp/certs/pki/private/ca.key:
Could not read CA private key from /tmp/certs/pki/private/ca.key
00065C0F01000000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:ossl_store_handle_load_result:unsupported:crypto/store/store_result.c:151:
00065C0F01000000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:
00065C0F01000000:error:11800074:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt_ex:pkcs12 cipherfinal error:crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:86:maybe wrong password

Easy-RSA error:

easyrsa_openssl - Command has failed:
* openssl ca -utf8 -batch -in /tmp/certs/pki/reqs/home-server.req -out /tmp/certs/pki/3bbd9f05/temp.3.1 -extfile /tmp/certs/pki/3bbd9f05/temp.2.1 -days 1095

EasyRSA Version Information
Version:     3.1.7
Generated:   Fri Oct 13 17:27:51 CDT 2023
SSL Lib:     OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023)
Git Commit:  3c233d279d43e419b0529411ee62bba7a08f0c0f
Source Repo: https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa
Host: 3.1.7 | nix | Darwin | /bin/zsh
```

I am absolutely 100% Sure that I am using the correct CA password that I created when I built my CA. What is going on here? How can I sign this request properly when using a CA password and openssl?